# my sidebar navigation button doesnt move along

Tags: javascript, html, css

the button does move along in glitch, but not if i add it to my project in intellij. also , if the first div class line is empty, it doesnt show me anything, i have to fill it with something ( i.e. added three underlines). please help me

```js
function show(){
    document.getElementById('sidebar').classList.toggle('active');
}
```

```css
#sidebar{
    position: absolute;
    width: 300px;
    height: 100%;
    background: #000;
    left: -300px;
    transition: .4s;
}


#sidebar.active{
    left: 0;
}

#sidebar ul li {
    list-style: none;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 20px 24px;
}

#sidebar .toggle-btn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    left: 330px;
}

.line{
    widht: 45px;
    height: 4px;
    background: #000;
    display: block;
    margin: 4px;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div id="root"></div>
<div id="sidebar">
    <div id="menueSymbol" class="toggle-btn" onclick="show()">
        <div class="line">___</div>
        <div class="line"></div>
        <div class="line"></div>
    </div>

    <ul>
        <li>Seites0</li>
        <li>Seite1</li>
        <li>Seite2</li>
        <li>Seite3</li>
    </ul>

</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have corrected the misspelled code, widht: 45px; from your code,

```js
function show(){
document.getElementById('sidebar').classList.toggle('active');
}
```

```css
#sidebar{
    position: absolute;
    width: 300px;
    height: 100%;
    background: #000;
    left: -300px;
    transition: .4s;
}


#sidebar.active{
    left: 0;
}

#sidebar ul li {
    list-style: none;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 20px 24px;
}

#sidebar .toggle-btn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    left: 330px;
}

.line{
    width: 45px;
    height: 4px;
    background: #000;
    display: block;
    margin: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<div id="sidebar">
    <div id="menueSymbol" class="toggle-btn" onclick="show()">
        <div class="line"></div>
        <div class="line"></div>
        <div class="line"></div>
    </div>

    <ul>
        <li>Seites0</li>
        <li>Seite1</li>
        <li>Seite2</li>
        <li>Seite3</li>
    </ul>

</div>
```

Comment: thanks, didnt saw that, fixed the issue with the emptiness!